# Conjunctive Normal Form of a clause

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, conjunctive-normal-form

Can the following clause be converted to [conjunctive normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form)?  If so how?

$$
(a \implies b) \implies (c \implies d)
$$

I tried applying DeMorgans laws and am unable to get the result.

$$
(a \implies b) \implies (c \implies d) = \lnot(\lnot a \lor b) \lor (\lnot c \lor d) = (a \land \lnot b) \lor (\lnot c \lor d)
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You made a good start but you've missed a $\lnot$ before $b$ in the last formula (EDIT: now fixed). After fixing that, use the distributivity law $(x \land y) \lor z = (x \lor z) \land (y \lor z)$ to lift the conjunction up to the top:
\begin{align*}
(a \implies b) \implies (c \implies d) &= \lnot(\lnot a \lor b) \lor (\lnot c \lor d) \\
   &= (a \land \lnot b) \lor (\lnot c \lor d) \\
   &= (a \lor \lnot c \lor d) \land (\lnot b \lor \lnot c \lor d)
\end{align*}

PS: every propositional formula can be converted to conjunctive normal form.

Comment: Thanks you clarified it!